# Despite vs although exercise. Why although is a valid answer here?

Tags: meaning, difference, formal-language

I have stumbled upon this CAE exercise today and I was surprised to discover that I made a mistake in the following sentence:

> *The events that make up the history of the Iberian Peninsula have shaped the history of the Spanish language. The Roman invasion is most fundamental in this respect, **although** other events have also been decisive.*

Instead of **although** I used **despite** as I learnt that despite usually goes before or in front of a noun or pronoun (For e.g. despite the rain, despite the events, etc).

There are also some good explanations here on stackexchange.com too.

Against this background, I used  *... **despite** the events ...* but it turned out to be a mistake.

Why? Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: _This website_? Which website? I think you forgot linking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The events that make up the history of the Iberian Peninsula have shaped the history of the Spanish language. The Roman invasion is most fundamental in this respect, **although** other events have also been decisive.

The usage of particular words is not always about grammar, but many a times about idiomatic usage in the context of speech.

- **although** - in spite of the fact that; even though. [Source](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=although+)
- **despite** - without being affected by; in spite of. [Source](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=despite)

Both the words have almost the same meanings, but depending on their usage could convey different meanings.

See this sentence: [Source of example](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/although)

> She walked home by herself, although she knew that it was dangerous.

***she*** is a pronoun, and ***although*** is present right before it. So you see, every time things don't work by the rules. You need to think, might be read the sentence out loud to see which word fits perfectly. Though some people would say this is an inefficient technique, it has helped me 50% of the times, if not more.

So coming back to your question, I would say the proper sentence would be the one you already wrote using "*although*". Because "*despite*" just doesn't fit right into this sentence, because the sentence conveys the message that **even though other events took place, the Roman invasion stood out and has been prominent.** Another alternative can be,

> The events that make up the history of the Iberian Peninsula have shaped the history of the Spanish language. The Roman invasion is most fundamental in this respect, **despite** other events (also) **being** decisive.